# Too many GetRecords count compared to PutRecords in Kinesis Stream resulting duplicate records

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, stream, duplicates, amazon-kinesis

I have a Kinesis Stream that has three shards and the Producer applications write to the stream with a random partition key. In Kinesis Metric, I found that the count of GetRecords.Records is almost double to that of PutRecords.Records count.

To be precise count (in a minute):

> PutRecords.Records: **10749**
>
> GetRecords.Records: **21496**

Because of this, the Kinesis Record Processor which is lambda in my case, is getting a lot of duplicate records.

AWS document does suggest there would be some duplicates by [“at least once” delivery mechanism of Kinesis stream.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/kinesis-record-processor-duplicates.html) But almost the double of GetRecords is not very appropriate. Here is my SAM template for the processor lambda.

```
  MyStream:
  Type: AWS::Kinesis::Stream
  Properties:
    Name: my-stream
    ShardCount: 3

  MyStreamProcessorLambda:
   Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
   Properties:
    FunctionName: my-stream-processor-lambda
   ...
   ...
   Events:
    Stream:
      Type: Kinesis
      Properties:
        Stream: !Ref MyStream
        BatchSize: 10000
        StartingPosition: LATEST
        MaximumBatchingWindowInSeconds: 300
```

The processor lambda is now, idempotent by enforcing a DB constraint such that same Record from the Batch will never be inserted in DB. Also the Error Rate of Lambda is 0. (***No errors/ retries by the lambda***)

Also the ***GetRecords.IteratorAgeMilliseconds***  in Stream Metrics is **0** and ***Read/Write ThroughputExceeded*** is **0.**

Thus, I would like to get rid of those Duplicate records in the Batch, the lambda is processing.

Any configuration that have gone wrong here ?

Comment: Given that the read count is almost exactly twice the write count, I'd first look for another Lambda that's consuming the stream.

Comment: I looked on the Recent invocation of lambda. There are 3 lambda getting invoked in an interval of 5 minutes as specified in Batch Window. 
Also the Concurrency is set to 20.

Comment: @krtsh Parsifal says that do you have any other lambda consuming this kinesis ? If there are two lambdas then getrecords will be twice as put records.

Comment: @Ersoy I don't have another lambda consuming that Kinesis. However I do have an enhanced fan-out consumer setup for that Kinesis Stream. Is it the reason that **SubscribeToShardEvent.Records** from fan-out consumer contributes for the additional **GetRecords** count ? Because SubscribeToShardEvent.Records count almost equals to **PutRecords** count.

Comment: If you are able to - just disable kinesis trigger from your aws lambda console for a while to see it(10~15 mins). It will keep consuming when you activate it. @krtsh

Comment: Yes I temporarily disabled the Kinesis trigger from lambda and then **PutRecords** count match (almost) with **GetRecords** because the **enhanced fan-out consumer** was still running. And when I enabled the trigger, there is again rise in **GetRecords** count making the count nearly a double. This explains a lots. So enhanced fan-out consumer **SubscribeToShard** also get records from **GetRecords.**

Comment: @krtsh Thanks for informing and glad to hear it is related to enhanced fan-out, it looks like both consumer's are using same method behind the scenes. Please post it as an answer - it may help someone too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems in Kinesis enhanced fan-out consumer, the **SubscribeToShard** also get all Records from **GetRecords** call. This is the reason the **GetRecords** count is almost twice as that of **PutRecords**.